# Ckeditor value and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I dont seem to be able to get the value from my ckeditior, any ideas where im going wrong?

```
<textarea  class="ckeditor" id="Source"></textarea> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SendPreview()" class="pOrange"> Send</a>
```

```js
function SendPreview() {
        var value = CKEDITOR.instances['Source'].getData();
        var model = { EmailBody: Source, EmailTo: "email@email.com", EmailSubject: $(".Subject").val() };
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: '/Campaign/SendPreviewEmail',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var dataAsString = JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: $("#ckeditior containerid").val();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have works, the problem is because you're setting the value of the CKEditor to the `value` variable, but using `Source` in your `model`. Try this:

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['Source'].getData();
var model = { 
    EmailBody: value, // <-- Change this
    EmailTo: "email@email.com",
    EmailSubject: $(".Subject").val() 
};
```

Comment: Ta, keep getting "http://localhost:5365/Campaign/SendPreviewEmail 500 (Internal Server Error) " tho, is it becuase its html in the value?

Comment: Yes I'd imagine so. If you're using ASP MVC you'll need to put the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on your controller action. If you're using other technologies I'm sure there's similar methods, but I'm not familiar with those.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below, This may help you to get your solution

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['Source'].getData();

    //or
    $('#Source').ckeditor(function( textarea ){
      $(textarea).val();
    });
```